# How to do ETL Automation Testing using C# or Python

Tags: automated-testing, manual-testing, pytest, etl

In my present project I m testing on reports which needs to be checked everyday manually by executing SQL queries for all columns from source tables, Dims and Facts tables and destination tables. Is it possible to do this Automate....?? Please help me

Answer (score 1):

When I first started out in Technical Operations I would run SQL scripts to verify the ETL processes we had running. Now that I had experience in SQA I would more likely write some unit tests so its easy to tell what failed using the reporting tools or the test runner(s).

You could create [unit tests in SQL Server](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssdt/walkthrough-creating-and-running-a-sql-server-unit-test?view=sql-server-ver15).

You could also create unit tests in Visual Studio using a [SQL connection string](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/test/walkthrough-using-a-configuration-file-to-define-a-data-source?view=vs-2019).

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I'll try creating the unit tests in visual studio. I have the script to connect to database but after that how can i validate the results from 3 different tables

Comment: [How To: Create a Data-Driven Unit Test](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2015/test/how-to-create-a-data-driven-unit-test?view=vs-2015&redirectedfrom=MSDN)

Comment: Thanks again for the response Kirbycope. Do you know any online sources that can help me in creating the data driven unit test framework

Comment: If the documentation is overwhelming, my go to is YouTube. There's usually some videos that take an hour or so that will really help you understand what the tool can do and if it is right for you. The trick is knowing how to break down your problems into Google-able chucks like, "mstest sql".